# How to get ubuntu 10.04 live cd for 64 bit pc

Tags: 10.04

can anybody give me a link for downloading Ubuntu 10.04 live cd/dvd 
for 64 bit desktop pc

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to download [Ubuntu 10.04](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.0/).  Keep in mind that support for the desktop version is no longer available, but for server its valid until 04/2015.

I would recommend downloading a current version, unless you have need for 10.04.

Here is the direct link for the [64bit desktop version](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.0/ubuntu-10.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso).

Comment: I need desktop version...if possible?

Comment: Added it in my answer.